# Correct way to scale ImageView

Tags: android, android-widget, scale

It seems to me that the way android scales bitmaps, with dpi profiles, is not correct.

For example I have a **320x533** image, that is meant to cover the entire screen area, defined as such:

```
<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="533dp" />
```

At hdpi (240 or 1.5) the image scales correctly to **480x800**. However at a xhdpi (320 or 2.0) does not! That is the image becomes **640x1066** but the actual phone area could be ***720x1280*** or ***1080x1920*** or other similar resolutions.

I have tried to adjust ImageView.scaleType (every option) but still the image does not scale correctly. What do you think is the correct way to handle this? Should I subclass the ImageView and handle the scaling with Java or am I missing something fundamental?

Answer (score 2):

"Should I subclass the ImageView and handle the scaling with Java"  NO

you can get the DPI value and you can get the resolution value too. Than you can calculate the desired number of pixels.

Option 2 is: use different directories based on android dpi. ( not only drawable, a google search will tell you exactly how )

Comment: But the problem is that android always scales * 2.0 at xhdpi while the actual ratio is different. 720px / 320px = 2.25 and 1080px / 320px = 3.375. You suggest that I make a different pre-scaled image for each different resolution?

Comment: the android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="533dp" can be overriden from the code. Just told above how to proceed: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html  and http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Comment: Well I have read those. They don't provide an answer to my problem. From the first link there are 2 suggestions. 1) Provide different layouts for different screen sizes (/res/layout-xyz). 2) Provide different bitmap drawables for different screen densities (/res/drawable-xyz). I could use (1) and adjust the layout xml for different sizes but that is a lot of work and kind of dumb IMO. What I need is scaling upon a ratio evaluated dynamically from the actual screen resolution, instead of a predefined value.

Comment: "For me it is a big difference in helping somebody or doing his job" no copy-paste code from me. I told how to do it, if you don't even want to TRY to understand and do it, that is ...

Comment: Man, I didn't mean to offend you! I sincerely thank you for the time you took  to respond to me.